# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0 (from cdqa)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

pip install cdqa

[image]
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `torch==1.2.0` (from cdqa) `(from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)`

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0 (from cdqa)

Any one came across this error.How can we resolve this error ?

Comment: Had you seen https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by executing the following command from my anaconda command prompt

```
conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 -c pytorch
```